# Why does some text not render correctly?

Tags: 14.04, screen-corruption

[image: Screenshot]

I've had this occur in multiple applications.

```
Ubuntu 14.04 (trusty)
Kernel 3.19.0-47-generic 
Xorg version 1.16.0 
Video Card Radeon R9 270
AMD FX-8370 - 4300 MHz
```

Comment: It's a bug in the radeon drivers.  Try upgrading to 15.10.